# Why Bokeh radioButtonGroup doesn't work in my django application?

Tags: python, django, bokeh

i'm trying to develope a webapp for my master thesis. I used Bokeh to do interactive plot, and i embedded it in a django app. The problem is that i don't manage to do something with js_on_change or js_on_click of radiobuttongroup.

This is my view:

```
def DTA_webAPP(request):
context={}
result = None
imps = pd.DataFrame(columns=["1","2","3","4","5"]) # i need this to avoid problem in create_grid in plotting.py
dta = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["3","4"])
fig = myfig(imps,dta)
script,div = components(fig.layout) 
form = DTAselection(request.POST,request.FILES)
if request.method == 'POST' and "Compute" in request.POST:
    if form.is_valid():
        data = pd.read_csv(request.FILES["ImportData"],sep = "\t",  skiprows = [1,2])
        imps, dta = main(data, form['method_of_discretization'].value(),float(form['regularization_parameter'].value()), int(form['regularization_order'].value()), int(form['number_of_point'].value()), form['col_selection'].value())
        fig = myfig(imps, dta)
        script, div = components(fig.layout)
        imps.to_csv("result_imps.csv", index = False)
        dta.to_csv("result_dta.csv", index = False)
        result = "Ok, boy"
context =  {'form': form, 'script':script, 'div':div, "result":result}
return HttpResponse(render(request, "dta_webapp.html", context))
```

the figure is created in the class myfig.

This is my class myfig:

```
LABELS = ["IMPS","REAL RESIDUALS", "IMAG RESIDUALS"]
 class myfig(object):
    def __init__(self, df_data, df_dta):
    self.df_data = df_data
    self.df_dta = df_dta

    self.radio_button_group = RadioButtonGroup(labels=LABELS, active=0)
    self.source = None
    self.plot = self.create_grid()
    self.radio_button_group.js_on_change('active', CustomJS(args=
            dict(s=self.source,
                p = self.plot.children[0],
                x = self.df_data.columns[1], 
                y = self.df_data.columns[2],
                ),
            code="""
                console.log('radio_button_group: active=' + this.active, this.toString());
                const s1 = new Bokeh.ColumnDataSource({data : {x: [3,4,5,6,6] , y:[3,4,5,6,4] }  }) ;
                s = s1;
                s.change.emit();
                 """))
    self.layout = layout([
           [self.radio_button_group],
            [self.plot],
       ])
   
def create_grid(self):
    plot_data=figure(title= "IMPS", x_axis_label="Y'",  y_axis_label="Y''")
    source_data = ColumnDataSource(data = self.df_data)
    vec_size = np.arange(0,len(self.df_data.columns), 1,dtype=int)
    #columns = int(len(self.df_data.columns)/(len(self.df_data.columns)/5)))
    data_to_plot = vec_size.reshape(int(len(self.df_data.columns)/5),5)
    palettes_ = RdYlGn[vec_size.size] 
    self.source = source_data
    for number, fix_voltage in enumerate(data_to_plot):
        plot_data.circle(x = self.df_data.columns[fix_voltage[1]], y = self.df_data.columns[fix_voltage[2]], source = self.source,color=palettes_[number])
        plot_data.line(x = self.df_data.columns[fix_voltage[3]], y = self.df_data.columns[fix_voltage[4]], source = self.source, color = palettes_[number], line_dash = "dashed")
    #plot_data.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name="Y''"), 'left')
    #plot_data.add_layout(LinearAxis(x_range_name="Y'"), 'below')
    freq = "@" + self.df_data.columns[0]
    TOOLTIPS=[
        ("freq" ,freq),
        ("x", "$x"),
        ("y", "$y"),]
    plot_data.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=TOOLTIPS))
    plot_dta = figure(title="DTA result",  x_axis_type="log",x_axis_label="Time (s)",  y_axis_label="DTA (V^-1)")
    source_dta = ColumnDataSource(data = self.df_dta)
        
    vec_size = np.arange(0,len(self.df_dta.columns), 1,dtype=int)
    data_to_plot = vec_size.reshape(int(len(self.df_dta.columns)/2),2)
    for number, fix_voltage in enumerate(data_to_plot):
        plot_dta.line(x = self.df_dta.columns[fix_voltage[0]], y = self.df_dta.columns[fix_voltage[1]], source = source_dta,color = palettes_[number],)
    freq ="@" + self.df_data.columns[0] 
    TOOLTIPS=[
        ("tau", "$x"),
        ("DTA", "$y"),]
    plot_dta.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=TOOLTIPS))
    grid = row(plot_data, plot_dta)
    return grid
```

I put this is in my html head:

```
    <!-- BOKEH DEPENDENCIES -->
<link href="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.4.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
<link href="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.4.0.min.css" rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css”>
```

and this at the very end of my html:

```
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-2.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-2.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-2.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-api-2.4.2.min.js"></script>
{{ script |safe}}  
</html>
```

I'm using Bokeh==2.4.2. In the css sources i put 1.4.0 version since with 2.4.2 as version rise an error. `GET https://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-2.4.2.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 403` , but i think write previous version of css is not a problem in the question i posed.

The warning i got in the compiler are the following:
[image: Image of warning]
I tryed a lot of stuff but my figure never update if i change the radio active button. The only thing i managed to obtain is a creation of new figure with a Bokeh.Plotting.show(plot) in the js callback, but this is not what i want. I want to change radically in xaxis and yaxis name, title, and data the two figures in the self.plot, created by the method create_grid(). This method return a row(figure1, figure2) that is stored in self.plot. I want to take control on figure1 figure2 by the callback . I tried to update the ColumnDataSource but nothing, i tried to change all the plot and do plot.change.emit() but nothing. What is wrong in my approach?

Comment: how do you embed it ? Where is your HTML? It may need to load JavaScript code to communicate between browser and server. You could also check in DevTools if there is no error messages. It may need also to check tab Network in DevTools to check if it has no problem to load some elements - JavaScript code.

Comment: i edited my question adding html and warning message in DevTools.

Answer (score 1):

For the css resources of latest versions of bokeh you can use bokeh.resources to get the dependencies.
Instead of this:

```
    <!-- BOKEH DEPENDENCIES -->
<link href="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.4.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
<link href="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-1.4.0.min.css" rel=”stylesheet” type=”text/css”>
```

Use this in the head part of your HTML:

```
{{ resources|safe }}
```

And in your view make these changes:

```
from bokeh.resources import CDN

context =  {'form': form, 'script':script, 'div':div, "result":result, 'resources':CDN.render()}
```

This will give you dependencies compatible with your version of bokeh.
And about the radio button part, I'm still not sure what you are trying to do and what is happening.